# Add Avatar (user profile photo) to Semantic UI React's Dropdown

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap, semantic-ui-react

As a side project I wrote a little app, and for themes and layout I used React-Bootsrap. Right now I'm trying to learn Semantic UI React & I can't figure out how to add user profile photo to the dropdown (originally got the idea from [Github's dropdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OqaJh.png))

This is [how it looks right now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jH6v2.png) in my app using React Bootstrap

React Bootstrap code:

```js
  <NavDropdown
      alignRight
      title={<StyledUserIMG src={user.photoURL} alt='userPhoto' />}
    >
      <NavDropdown.ItemText>
        Signed in as <b>{user.displayName}</b>
      </NavDropdown.ItemText>
      <NavDropdown.Item onClick={async () => await signOut()}>
        <b>Sign Out </b>
        <i className='fas fa-sign-out-alt'></i>
      </NavDropdown.Item>
    </NavDropdown>
```

Semantic UI code (what I have so far):

```js
<Dropdown item>
  <Dropdown.Item>
    Signed in as <b>{user.displayName}</b>
  </Dropdown.Item>
  <Dropdown.Item onClick={async () => await signOut()}>
    <b>Sign Out </b> <i className='fas fa-sign-out-alt'></i>
  </Dropdown.Item>
</Dropdown>
```

Thank you in advance, wish y'all the best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works on same principle as Alex Court suggested, just doesn't throw expected text error.

found it on:

https://react.semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown/#usage-trigger

```js
import React from 'react'
import { Dropdown, Image } from 'semantic-ui-react'

export const DropdownMenu = () => (

const trigger = <Image avatar src={user.photoURL} />;

const options = [
  {
    key: 'user',
    text: (
      <span>
         Signed in as <strong>{user.displayName}</strong>
      </span>
    ),
    disabled: true,
  },
  
    {
      key: 'settings',
      text: 'Settings',
      icon: 'setting',
    },
    {
      key: 'signOut',
      text: 'Sign Out',
      icon: 'sign out alternate',
    },
  ];
return (

  <Dropdown trigger={trigger} options={options} />
)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import React from 'react'
import { Dropdown } from 'semantic-ui-react'

const friendOptions = [
  {
    key: 'Jenny Hess',
    text: 'Jenny Hess',
    value: 'Jenny Hess',
    image: { avatar: true, src: 'https://react.semantic-ui.com/images/avatar/small/jenny.jpg' },
  },
  {
    key: 'Elliot Fu',
    text: 'Elliot Fu',
    value: 'Elliot Fu',
    image: { avatar: true, src: 'https://react.semantic-ui.com/images/avatar/small/elliot.jpg' },
  },
  {
    key: 'Stevie Feliciano',
    text: 'Stevie Feliciano',
    value: 'Stevie Feliciano',
    image: { avatar: true, src: 'https://react.semantic-ui.com/images/avatar/small/stevie.jpg' },
  },
  {
    key: 'Christian',
    text: 'Christian',
    value: 'Christian',
    image: { avatar: true, src: 'https://react.semantic-ui.com/images/avatar/small/christian.jpg' },
  },
]

const DropdownExampleInline = () => (
  <span>
    Show me posts by{' '}
    <Dropdown
      inline
      options={friendOptions}
      defaultValue={friendOptions[0].value}
    />
  </span>
)

export default DropdownExampleInline
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. really appreciate it. i saw this on semantic ui's site, but i still dont understand how this will work for me as i dont precode avatar src, i extract it from there google account. and i dont need to have choice of people i need the logged in persons avatar be the button for the dropdown or be a clickable aspect that will trigger the dropdown menu.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a component to the Dropdown text prop.
Pass in the image as a component to the 'text' prop.

```
const DropdownExampleDropdown = () => (
  <Dropdown 
      text={<span><Image avatar src={'https://react.semantic-ui.com/logo.png'} /></span>}
      options={optionsList}
   />
)

export default DropdownExampleDropdown
```